# how to watch forum groups in multidimensional form for changes and make custom ajax query

Tags: jquery, forms, multidimensional-array

i have a client who wants a bulk payment enter system that was easy 
my issue is having it make sure the data can be entered to the database

here is the type of form i have

```
<form name="add_payment_bulk" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control col-lg-4" placeholder="Player Number" name="pay[1][client_id]" id="client_id" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control col-lg-4" placeholder="Payment" name="pay[1][amount]" id="amount" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control col-lg-4" placeholder="Player Number" name="pay[2][client_id]" id="client_id" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control col-lg-4" placeholder="Payment" name="pay[2][amount]" id="amount" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control col-lg-4" placeholder="Player Number" name="pay[3][client_id]" id="client_id" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control col-lg-4" placeholder="Payment" name="pay[3][amount]" id="amount" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control col-lg-4" placeholder="Player Number" name="pay[4][client_id]" id="client_id" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control col-lg-4" placeholder="Payment" name="pay[4][amount]" id="amount" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control col-lg-4" placeholder="Player Number" name="pay[5][client_id]" id="client_id" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
                <input class="form-control col-lg-4" placeholder="Payment" name="pay[5][amount]" id="amount" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

</form>
```

i need to match each row pay[1][client_id] and pay[1][amount] and send them over a ajax query to make sure the entry will work BUT only when the amount is entered

i have tryed several jquery code bytes shown here

```
$('.form-control').on('change',function() {

    var form = $('.form-control');
    if (form.children("div").children("input#amount").val())
    {
        var client = form.children("div").children("input#client_id").val();
        var amount = form.children("div").children("input#amount").val();

        console.log(client);
        console.log(amount);
    }
});

$('.form-control').each(function () { 

    var form = $(this);
    $(this).children("div").children("input#amount").on('change',function() {
        var client = $form.children("div").children("input#client_id").val();
        var amount = $form.children("div").children("input#amount").val();

        console.log(client);
        console.log(amount);
    });
});

$('.form-group').on('change',function() {
    console.log($(this));
    var client = $(this).children("div").children("input#client_id").val();
    var amount = $(this).children("div").children("input#amount").val();

    console.log(client);
    console.log(amount);
    // validation here? 
    //$('#status').empty();

    // end validation

    $.ajax({  
        type: "GET",  
         url: "pages/clientidcheck.php",  
        data: "clientid="+ emailaddress,  
        success: function(msg)
        {
            console.log(msg);
            if (msg == 'yes')
            {
                $("#client_id_check").parent('div').addClass('has-success');
            }
            else
            {
                $("#client_id_check").parent('div').addClass('has-error');
            }
        }
     });

});
```

ideally i would like this to return and i can set success or error for the forum group based on my return but the client_id and amount for each row when changed is what i need done

Comment: You cannot have duplicate ids jQ/JS will only find the first id assuming that it's unique and stop searching. Suffix an incremental number to each one `#amount0`, `#amount1` , etc

Comment: oh ok well that makes this undo able then for what i want to do ial have to resort to code checks